# TFS 2010 Build Process Template

Tags: workflow, build-process, hyper-v

When choosing the *LabDefaultTemplate* then there is the option to revert the environment to a certain snapshot before test execution.

Now is it possible to revert the virtual machines used in the testsettings files back to a certain snapshot when using the **DefaultTemplate**?

There is no intellisense support and i cant figure out how this could be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can try editing your **DefaultTemplate** so that the Activity "RestoreLabEnvironment" is inserted and used. I think this does what you are looking for, since it sets a specific `SnapshotId` to a Lab Environment defined by its `LabEnvironmentUri`:
[image]
Activity resides under `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Workflow.Activities`, and in the VS-Toolbox under "Team Foundation LabManagement Activities".

Answer (score 0):

The default template has no support for lab management.

Why not just switch to using the Lab Management template?